# Missing ; before statement Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Javascript, my error is Missing ; before statement on Line 25.

The other question was Java related, not JavaScript related.

Here is the code that is problematic.

Line 24  function emailChecker(){

Line 25  var readMessages() = DocumentApp.create();

Line 26  var emailAddress() = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

Line 27  GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();

Line 28  var unreadMessages() = InboxUnreadCount();

Line 29  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress) (You have + unreadMessages + unread messages!)
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at `var readMessages() = ...`. when you write `var x = something;`, you are assigning `something` to the variable `x`. Brackets are used for functions, not variables. Try this instead:

```
var readMessages = DocumentApp.create();
```